# Adding objects to an array based on a String attribute?

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist

I'm coding an application for a year-long school project, and its purpose is to display articles for teens to read that educate them on current events.

I want to make several different `ArrayList`s of categories to store the Articles in. The objects are `Article(String URL, String Category, String title)`

I'm wondering if, instead of doing this:

```
Article p = new Article(
    "http://www.google.com", "economics", "Potato Article");
if(category.equals("elections"))
    elections.add(p);
if(category.equals("economics"))
    economics.add(p);
// etc.
```

If there is some thing I can do like this:

```
String name = category;
(something).something(name);
name.add(p);
```

So basically I want to add the article to an `ArrayList` of the same name as its category, assuming the `ArrayList` is made already, and the category of the particular article matches the desired `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 3):

Data structure should be `Map<String, List<Article>>`, so a sample code could be as follows :

```
Map<String, List<Article>> map =
    new HashMap<String, List<Article>>();

map.put("elections", new ArrayList<Article>());
map.put("economics", new ArrayList<Article>());

Article article1 = new Article(
    "http://www.google.com", "economics", "Potato");
Article article2 = new Article(
    "http://www.yyy.com", "elections", "xxx");

map.get(article1.getCategory()).add(article1);
map.get(article2.getCategory()).add(article2);
```